# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation- driven'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'll use spring mvc and hibernate.
When i start server, "org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread" error is occurs.
So, I search what's the problem.
I find serveral things. one is use

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />.
```

and I added. but, `"The prefix "tx" for element "tx:annotation-driven" is not bound."` error occurs.
So, i search answer again and get answer and then apply it.
That is using `xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd"`.
But, - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-
     driven'. and Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for element 'tx:annotation-driven' of schema namespace 'http://
     www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd' error is occurs.
When i search answer, it is recursively repeated.
How can I solve this problem? help me...

It is my servlet-context.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jinggumdari" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="mysql1234" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.Member</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="memberDAO" class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.MemberDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="memberService"
        class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation.MemberManageServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="memberDAO" ref="memberDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration is wrong. Defining a namespace and schema location are 2 different things. Don't put `xmlns:tx` inside the `xis:schemaLocation` that should be `http:`.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
```

In short remove `xmlns:tx="` from the `xsi:schemaLocation`.

Another tip use the versionless schema instead of a versioned one.

Comment: I try this one. When i apply this change, "The prefix "tx" for element "tx:annotation-driven" is not bound." error occurs. how to solve this problem?

Comment: There was an additional `"` in the schema location fixed it. Also make sure you are removing the right one!!!

Answer (score 1):

You miss

```
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
```

in your beans declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">
```

Comment: "xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
There is at last of attribute, Isn't it?